# Unable to load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, iis-7, telerik

A little disclaimer before I begin discussing my problem: I have no idea what I'm doing. I don't know anything about Windows servers. I don't know anything about ASP.NET and I don't know anything about IIS. I'm a Linux and PHP kind of guy but I've got put on this project anyway.

My task is to move a current site to a new server. I'm using Rackspace, and I attempted to just make an image of the old server and build the new server with it. However the old server is huge and the new server is a whole lot smaller so it couldn't be done. I ended up just made a new Windows server, copied the files from the older server, pasted them locally, and then copied them and moved them onto the new server. I have a feeling this is where I went wrong first.

I then installed IIS, made my Application Pool, and my first site, and then moved my new files onto it. I loaded it on my server's browser and got this error:

[image]

It reads:

```
 Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
```

I believe the issue is that it cannot add the assembly "everything" (*). I don't understand this, so I keep reading and I discover if I want to read what's causing my error I have to turning on assembling binding logging.

However, I don't know how to turn this on. I did some research and it says to just search "Fusion" and you should have it appear like so:

[image]

But when I try it:

[image]

Then I go back and try just removing the add assembly="*" line and I get the following errors.

[image]

I believe the NamespaceName in question is unique to the project because the project is called "Kids in Motion", so "InMotion" would be an acceptable abbreviate.

But still the error message:

```
 Compiler Error Message: BC32035: Attribute specifier is not a complete statement. Use a line continuation to apply the attribute to the following statement.
```

Means nothing to me. Even doing a quick online search for the error doesn't turn up anything I understand.

I'm not sure where to go from here, and because I have no idea I'm not sure if this is a huge issue or a minor bug or what.

If somebody could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the second error, but the first indicates that the Telerik.Web.UI asembly that you are using is not built against the right .NET framework.

Go to your project properties in VS and see what .NET version it targets (probably .NET 3.5 judging from your first screenshot) and replace the Telerik.Web.UI.dll reference with the proper one. You can take it from the Bin35 folder in your installation (for .Net 3.5, for .NET 4.0 you will need the assemblies from bin40).

Try fixing this, and also make sure your app pool also targets the same .NET version (3.5 I believe, which is shown as 2.0.5)